# How to apply multiple different functions to columns in Polars GroupBy

Tags: python-polars

I have a Polars Dataframe that contains 3D spatial coordinates (x, y, z). The coordinates may be defined in either rectangular, cylindrical or spherical systems. The coordinate systems may be local (translated/rotated with respect to global)
The Dataframe contains the coordinate values, an ID to identify which coordinate system was used to define the coordinates and the type of this coordinate system. A representative dataframe is included below.
I'm trying to do three things with the data in this dataframe,

1. Convert all cylindrical/spherical data to rectangular (x=r(cos(theta)), y=r(sin(theta)) etc.)
2. Multiply each coordinate by a 3x3 rotation matrix
3. Offset each coordinate by a translation vector

The translation vectors and rotation matrices are available in another data structure that uses the coordinate system ID as key.

There can be 10s to 100s of millions of coordinates in the Dataframe so speed is very important so I'm thinking Polars Expressions would be appropriate.

I can see how to use GroupBy - first by CID_TYPE and then by CID.

On the GroupBy CID_TYPE, for coordinates with type 'C' (Cylindrical) I need to be able to update the first two coordinates using x=x(cos(y)), y=x(cos(y)).

On the GROUPBY CID, I need to be able to multiple each [X, Y, Z] coordinate with a 3x3 rotation matrix and add an offset vector.

I can easily see how to do this by iterating over the groups, extracting the group data into numpy arrays, updating the dat and then pushing back into the dataframe.

However I'm a Polars noob and and I suspect that there are faster ways to do this with Polars expressions, but I just can't figure them out...... How can I apply different expressions to different groupings?

Any help will be gratefully received.

Note that the real data has 10s of millions of rows. Typically the number of unique CIDs is very small in relation to the number of coordinates.

```
 df = pl.DataFrame({
        'ID' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        'CID' : [1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11],
        'CID_TYPE' : ['C', 'R', 'S', 'C', 'R', 'S'],
        'COORDS' :[
                    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
                    [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
                    [7.0, 8.0, 9.0],
                    [10.0, 11.0, 12.0],
                    [13.0, 14.0, 15.0],
                    [16.0, 17.0, 18.0]
                    ]
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'd say I'm not sure a `groupby` is needed here. Polars has an if-else construct called [`when`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html#polars.when) to operate separate expressions on column(s).

I ended up [`unnest`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest)ing the COORD lists into separate X/Y/Z columns because that is easier to work with in polars (editing one element of a list at a time is a pain). So for part 1 of your question:

```py
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("COORDS").arr.to_struct(name_generator=lambda i: "XYZ"[i])
).unnest("COORDS")

df.with_columns(
    X=pl.when(pl.col("CID_TYPE") == "C")
    .then(pl.col("X") * pl.col("Y").cos())
    .when(pl.col("CID_TYPE") == "S")
    .then(pl.col("X") * pl.col("Y").cos() * pl.col("Z").sin())
    .otherwise(pl.col("X")),
    Y=pl.when(pl.col("CID_TYPE") == "C")
    .then(pl.col("X") * pl.col("Y").sin())
    .when(pl.col("CID_TYPE") == "S")
    .then(pl.col("X") * pl.col("Y").sin() * pl.col("Z").sin())
    .otherwise(pl.col("Y")),
    Z=pl.when(pl.col("CID_TYPE") == "S")
    .then(pl.col("X") * pl.col("Z").cos())
    .otherwise(pl.col("Z")),
)
```

```
shape: (6, 6)
┌─────┬─────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ ID  ┆ CID ┆ CID_TYPE ┆ X         ┆ Y         ┆ Z         │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str      ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═════╪═════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ C        ┆ -0.416147 ┆ 0.909297  ┆ 3.0       │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ R        ┆ 4.0       ┆ 5.0       ┆ 6.0       │
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ S        ┆ -0.419743 ┆ 2.85413   ┆ -6.377912 │
│ 4   ┆ 9   ┆ C        ┆ 0.044257  ┆ -9.999902 ┆ 12.0      │
│ 5   ┆ 10  ┆ R        ┆ 13.0      ┆ 14.0      ┆ 15.0      │
│ 6   ┆ 11  ┆ S        ┆ 3.306307  ┆ 11.551956 ┆ 10.565067 │
└─────┴─────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

For parts 2 to 3, I'd say joining your separate tables to this one on `CID_TYPE` so each row has the right rotations & translations, is the way to go and then you can operate from there. I'm not sure about matrix multiplication in polars without a custom function, but there is [`dot`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dot.html#polars.Expr.dot).

Comment: This is great!!!!  I have freedom to construct the tables with separate X, Y, Z columns so that's not an issue. I originally chose to put them in lists because I figured the matrix multiple might be easier. Next up I need to read up ion joining the CID tables to this one.....

Comment: If you do all the x=, y=, z= inside a struct then you only have to have the conditions once instead of for each of xyz. Like `pl.when(condition).then(pl.struct(x=pl.col("X") * pl.col("Y").cos(), y=...,z=...))`

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Is that faster performance-wise or is it the same, despite my version being more verbose?

Comment: I'll try both and check performance

Comment: I tested both suggested approaches for performance. The more verbose approach proposed by @Wayoshi is faster. On my machine, around 3.8 seconds to transform 100,000,000 coordinates v's 6.5 seconds using the struct approach. I tried a third approach using the original struct column plus the struct manipulation to see if the cost of adding a new column made a difference - but it did not.... Just for grins I did a standalone numpy solution and it performed between the two Polars approaches. I though about using numexpr to speed up the numpy approach but numexpr doesn't support array slicing :(

Comment: I think the more verbose approach works because it results ion better parallelism. Eyeballing CPU usage shows higher core utilization for the verbose approach than for the other

Comment: Just to finish this off....... I went ahead and refactored my code so that I could use numexpr and numpy and the time to covert 100,000,000 coordinates fell to 1.9 seconds. That's almost twice as fast as the best I could achieve with Polars - albeit at the cost of more code. My takeaway is that for performance sensitive row based operations I'll likely continue to use numpy/numexpr.